# Regarding tbb::tbb_thread for C++

Tags: c++, tbb

I am trying to use TBB in C++, and looking for tutorial on tbb_thread. can any one provide link or tutuorial regarding tbb_thread like what are the interfaces and how it is used, is tbb_thread is nothing but thread API but only it is portable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: I must say upfront that threads are not the primary feature of TBB, and are only recommended for few specific cases such as separation of GUI and computing. My recommendation is to look whether/how TBB parallel algorithms and/or tasks can be applied to your problem.

Probably, the best source of information is TBB Reference Manual (available at http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/documentation.php). It describes the API of the class (which is now provided as `std::thread` and recommended to use with platforms/compilers where this C++11 feature is not available; the old `tbb::tbb_thread` name is deprecated but available).

In TBB implementation, `std::thread` has some deviations from what is prescribed in C++11 standard, some of which, as well as the reasons for the deviations, are explained in blogs at [Intel(R) Software Network](http://software.intel.com) (see [Tasks for Doing and Threads for Waiting](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2008/06/05/tasks-for-doing-and-threads-for-waiting/) and [Transitioning to TBB 3.0](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2010/05/04/transitioning-to-tbb-30/)).

You are also welcome at [the TBB forum](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-threading-building-blocks).

Comment: @Julio: No, the other way around. TBB provides a partially compatible implementation of `std::thread` for platforms where C++11 implementation is not available. If C++11 is available, one should better use threads from there.

Comment: But the good thing about TBB is not only the threads, there are plenty other good functionalities (e.g. pipelines, etc.). I would not surprised to see TBB features compatible with C++0x threads (to be tested).